# Accessing ResourceException in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm doing something in an Eclipse plugin that throws a ResourceException. I in turn need to know what the path of the resource involved is.

I can do this via `((ResourceStatus) caughtException.getStatus()).getPath()` , however I then get admonished with `Discouraged access: The type 'ResourceException' is not API` (same warning for `ResourceStatus`). Should I just ignore the warning, or is there a better way for me to get the path? I'm just worried that this might change later on.

*Technically* I could extract the path from the exception's message, but that feels gross & have back luck with scraping data out of human-presentable strings :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceException` extends `CoreException` which is part of the official API so you can catch that.

`ResourceStatus` implements `IResourceStatus` which again is an official API.

So something like:

```java
catch (CoreException ex) {
  IStatus status = ex.getStatus();

  if (status instanceof IResourceStatus) {
    IPath path = ((IResourceStatus)status).getPath();

    ....
  }
}
```

`IResourceStatus` also contains the definitions of the error codes that `IStatus.getCode` returns for a resource exception.

Comment: Thanks a million for this. It's perfect for the task @ hand, and enlightening as to how eclipse wants me to do things. Very cool :-D